# Create new column from agg function by group

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I used the following code to summarize a large data set into aggregate level so that I can draw graph.

```py
a = b.groupBy("year","month").agg(sum("dollar")/sum("value").alias("pct"))
```

But when calling a's column 'pct, I have the following error:

```py
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o16779.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`pct`' given input columns:
```

Do you know how to create new column 'pct' under agg function so that I can use later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enclosing your division in **`()`** then do **`.alias()`**

```
a = b.groupBy("year","month").agg((sum("dollar")/sum("value")).alias("pct"))

#now you can select pct column from a
a.select("pct").show()
```

Comment: BTW, do you know how to format this into percentage so that when using display function by Databricks notebook, it would show percentage in the chart?